# Splitting array not working in android

Tags: android

I am splitting a string with some sample text in the middle. But it is not splitting. Please help me where i went wrong

```
String[] str;

parts[1] = "loopstWatch out this is testingloopstThis makes the difference";
str = parts[1].trim().split("loopst");
```

Comment: It would help if we knew the error message (or the "wrong" output").

Comment: When i am trying to print str value it is displaying nothing

Comment: So you want to split the string with delimiter as 'loopst'?

Comment: yes wat is the error in it plz tell me

Comment: @user1448108 It is working check here http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/15624

Comment: @user1448108 Do you want to remove "loost" from the above string?

Comment: From the string i want to get str[0]=Watch out this is testing str[1]=This makes the difference

Comment: @user1448108 I have posted the answer...Check once..

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr;
                arr = "loopstWatch out this is testingloopstThis makes the difference".trim().split("loopst");
                Log.e("Data arr[0]",":"+arr[0]);
                Log.e("Data arr[1]",":"+arr[1]);
                Log.e("Data arr[2]",":"+arr[2]);
```

**Output**

```
 arr[0] :""
arr[1] :"Watch out this is testing"
arr[2] :"This makes the difference"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it backwards.

You want to first split, then get the piece at index 1, then trim, then set str equal to the result:

```
String s = "loopstWatch out this is testingloopstThis makes the difference";
String str = s.split("loopst")[1].trim();

// str should be equal to "Watch out this is testing"
```